# Cluster name within the Pod

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-pod

Is there a way to get the name of the cluster within the pod. Is there a fieldRef that can be used to pass on the cluster name to the pod while creating the pod using the deployment.yaml file?

Comment: Where do you run your K8s? There is a way to do it in GKE, not sure about the other clouds.

Comment: The cluster doesn't know its own name.  In addition to this statement, answers to the linked question also describe how to find the GKE name as @jabbson suggests, if you're in that environment, and has lots of suggestions to use `kubectl config current-context`, which won't work in-cluster (and doesn't return a stable name in any case).